# how to fix error ./configure error configure: error

Tags: execute-command, configure

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libczmq > 2.0) were not met:

No package 'libczmq' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CZMQ_CFLAGS
and CZMQ_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

How can I fix this I have installed libzmq-dev which contains libczmq
I am on a machine with Xubuntu 14.04 64-bit installed

Answer (score 0):

libzmq-dev does not contain lib**c**zmq. Note the extra "c".

libczmq is a different library that apparently is not packaged for Ubuntu. Its [web page](https://github.com/jaeheum/qzmq/blob/master/how-to-install-zeromq-czmq.md) says that for Ubuntu:

```
Installing ZeroMQ and CZMQ from source code is recommended.
```

Further down the same page you will find instructions how to do that.